# MEL function call when radio button selected

Tags: function, radio-button, maya, mel

**I solved it by clearing keyframes at points, I will post my solution when the site lets me**. Thanks for your thoughts!

Pretty new to MEL!

I wrote this function that, if radio button 1 is selected, it rotates ball 1 and then animates it (call to the oneballanim function).

On the other hand, if radio button 2 is selected, it rotates the two balls and then calls the function that animates both of them.

```
 global proc rotaterandanim() {
     if (`radioButtonGrp -q -select myRadBtnGrp` == 1) setAttr ball1.rotateZ 15;
     if (`radioButtonGrp -q -select myRadBtnGrp` == 1) oneballanim();

     //second radio button
     if (`radioButtonGrp -q -select myRadBtnGrp` == 2) setAttr ball1.rotateZ 15;
     if (`radioButtonGrp -q -select myRadBtnGrp` == 2) setAttr ball2.rotateZ 15;
     if (`radioButtonGrp -q -select myRadBtnGrp` == 2) twoballanim();         
 }
```

The problem is that when I run the script, it actually animates and moves BOTH balls, even when radio button 1 is selected!! What can I do to fix that?

Comment: This code seems fine to me, can you edit your question and add these functions `oneballanim()` and `twoballanim()`?

Comment: @DrHaze Yes, doing right now!

Answer (score 0):

You likely have something else going on here that is not easy to see without seeing the rest of the code.  Just a suggestion, you should consolidate your IF/ELSE statements (see below).  I tried the following, and it seemed to catch each selection fine without doing both at the same time (which is why I said there is something else going on here that we can't see without more code).  Try the following... and keep executing rotaterandanim() after you select the button 1 or 2 each time, it prints out properly and only rotates what should rotate.

```
//    Create a window with two separate radio button groups.
//
string $window = `window`;
columnLayout;
radioButtonGrp  -numberOfRadioButtons 2
    -label "Two Buttons" -labelArray2 1 2
    -select 1
    myRadBtnGrp;
showWindow $window;

global proc rotaterandanim() {
    if (`radioButtonGrp -q -select myRadBtnGrp` == 1) {
        setAttr ball1.rotateZ 15;
        oneballanim();
    }
    //second radio button
    else if (`radioButtonGrp -q -select myRadBtnGrp` == 2) {
        setAttr ball1.rotateZ 15;
        setAttr ball2.rotateZ 15;
        twoballanim();  
    }       
}

global proc oneballanim() {
    print("OneBallAnim");
}

global proc twoballanim() {
    print("TwoBallAnim");
}
```

Comment: You're right, I think it's because in oneballanim and twoballanim I set keyframes, maybe I need to clear keyframes after each bit. I will edit to show one of the functions (oneballanim)

Comment: Yep if it's being keyed, no matter what you set rotate to it will always just go back to the keyed value.  Hope that helps, goodluck!

Comment: so should I do a sort of clear all keyframes before each new time I set?

Comment: That depends on what you want.  Do you wish to preserve the keyframe that is there, or overwrite it?  Or would you rather have no keys on it at all and just a static value?  If you want to overwrite it at a specific time, just key over it.  If you don't want keys on it at all, then I would just delete the keys and set the value.

Comment: Took a look at the new snippet of code...  and what is confusing is what both1, both2, both7, and both6 refer to.  Are these GROUPS?  If so, it almost looks like you are keying/moving the GROUPS and perhaps you have both balls somehow connected to these groups (either parented underneath, or through some kind of constraint or connection).  It's honestly hard to tell what the exact issue is without seeing your scene, but that is the likely cause if you are seeing both move.

Comment: sorry, 'both' are objects, bad name that makes sense to me. each 'both' is a sphere and stem put together. pretend those say ball1... ballX instead